# React native context api not passing value properly, null is not an object (evaluating 'user.uid')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-context

I want to retrieve a field value of a document in Users collection by referencing it via the **where** condition from Firestore. I use the context api to pass the **user** object of the logged in user in my app. I get this error that **user.uid** is null. I can't spot where the mistake is. I have added the relevant piece of code.

**EditProfile.js**

```
const EditProfile = () => {
  const { user } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const [name, setName] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const userid = user.uid;
    const name = getFieldValue("Users", userid);
    setName(name);
  }, []);

  
};

export default EditProfile;
```

**passing and getting value via context**

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <BottomTab.Navigator>
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="ProfileStack"
          component={ProfileStack}
        />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default AppStack;
```

**ProfileStack.js**

```
export const ProfileStack = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="EditProfile"
        component={EditProfile}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**getFieldValue** function

```
export const getFieldValue = (collection, userid) => {
    firestore()
      .collection(collection)
      .where("userid", "==", userid)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.size === 0) {
          return "";
        }
        if (querySnapshot.size === 1) {
          const { name } = querySnapshot[0].data();
          return name;
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
```

**Routing file**

```
const Routes = () => {

  // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = React.useState(true);
  const { user, setUser } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  // Handle user state changes
  const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    RNBootSplash.hide();
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Comment: It seems that `user` is `null` or `undefined` in `const userid = user.uid;`. You should probably check with `if (user`, before using it.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, yes it is null, but why? User is logged into the app.

Comment: You initially set `user` to `React.useState(null);`

Comment: yes but app monitors authentication state changes when the app loads. **EditProfile** component is rendered only when there is a user a signed in.